# Want buttons be displayed ONLY when clicking on another button with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have updated my question. So, I formulate again my problem: I have a set of buttons ("Backgrounds", "Ears", "Hair", "Eyes", "Mouth", "Legs", "Neck", "Accessories"). And I want that by clicking on each one  of its buttons, to see another group of buttons generated from the trigger button. This means that the buttons generated by "Backgrounds" are different from any other button like "Ears" or "Hair". So the buttons that should be displayed are from"Backgrounds" only and not from any other one. And if I click on another button like "Accessories", the buttons for "backgrounds" should disappear and only those for "Accessories" should be displayed. Before, I had tried an If else {} statement. now I want to try a switch {} statement . And this is how I wrote it: So please tell me, in order to fix the issue, what is missing in this code?

```
function myFunction(id){
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  switch (x) {
      case id="Backgrounds":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
      case id="Ears":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
      case id="Hair":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
      case id="Eyes":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
      case id="Mouth":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
      case id="Legs":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
      case  id="Neck":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
      case  id="Acessories":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        }
        
     }
```

Here how I wrote my code before:

```
/*
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}  
*/

 
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Backgrounds')" class="rightButton">Backgrounds</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Ears')" class ="rightButton">Ears</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Hair')" class ="rightButton">Hair</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Eyes')" class ="rightButton">Eyes</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Mouth')" class ="rightButton">Mouth</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Legs')" class ="rightButton">Legs</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Neck')" class ="rightButton">Neck</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Accessories')" class ="rightButton">Accessories</button>
        <hr>  
       

        <div id="Backgrounds" ><p class="para">Backgrounds</p>
        <button type="button" class="rightSubButton">Blue50</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Blue60</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Blue70</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Darkblue30</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Darkblue50</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Darkblue70</button>
        <button type="button" class="rightSubButton">Green50</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Green60</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Green70</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Grey40</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Grey70</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Grey80</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Red50</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Red60</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Red70</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Yellow50</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Yellow60</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Yellow70</button>
      </div>
        <div id="Ears" ><p class="para">Ears</p>
          <button type="button" class="rightSubButton">Default</button>
          <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Tilt-backward</button>
          <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Tilt-forward</button>
      </div>
```

The goal is to get the "rightSubButtons" displayed when ONLY clicking on each of the previous buttons associated with.

```
#Backgrounds , #Ears , #Hair , #Eyes , #Legs , #Mouth ,#Neck , #Accessories { 
    display: none; 
  
  }
```

Comment: what is missing is the the code hides/shows buttons

Comment: I removed a bunch of HTML to make it more readable.

Comment: P.S. to hide in css, use the hash tag to get the id: `#Backgrounds { display: none; }`. Then work on the js to show/hide.

Comment: @wazz, I know  I have created many buttons( I agree with you. There are too many) but they have to be displayed on the web page . What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want 'none' not 'hide'

```
if (x.style.display === "none")
```

Plain js is display `block` or `none`. Or, visibility `hidden` or `visible`.

Comment: I did that. But this did not fix the issue. You see , I need at first to see only the main buttons be displayed and only, when clicking for the first time only, see the sub-buttons appeared.

Comment: Right, there are several other things you need to do first, like add the css that will hide things. Then you might have to use getComputedStyle, etc. First figure out how to add the css to show and hide what you need in the first place. Then try the js to show/hide on click. Update your question at that point. (P.S. don't ask people to do all the work. break it down into small chunks and it's not bad.)