# Generating new buttons from one with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a post about this problem [Want buttons be displayed ONLY when clicking on another button with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68553338/want-buttons-be-displayed-only-when-clicking-on-another-button-with-js) and I have not gotten a satisfying answer. I formulate my problem again. I have to find a right JS code to solve this issue. I have a set of buttons ("Backgrounds", "Ears", "Hair", "Eyes", "Mouth", "Legs", "Neck", "Accessories"). And I want that by clicking on each one of its buttons, to see another group of buttons generated from the trigger button. This means the buttons generated by "Backgrounds" must be different from any other button like "Ears" or "Hair". So the buttons that should be displayed are from "Backgrounds" only and not from any other one. And if I click on another button like "Accessories", the buttons for "backgrounds" should disappear and only those for "Accessories" should be displayed. Before, I had tried an If else {} statement. now I want to try a switch {} statement . And this is how I wrote it: So please tell me, in order to fix the issue, what is missing in this code?

```
function myFunction(id){
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  switch (x) {
      case id="Backgrounds":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
      case id="Ears":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
      case id="Hair":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
      case id="Eyes":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
      case id="Mouth":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
      case id="Legs":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
      case  id="Neck":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
      case  id="Acessories":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        }
        
     }
```

Here is how before I have written the code:

```
/*
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}  
*/  



<div class="rightDiv">
          
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Backgrounds')" class="rightButton">Backgrounds</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Ears')" class ="rightButton">Ears</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Hair')" class ="rightButton">Hair</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Eyes')" class ="rightButton">Eyes</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Mouth')" class ="rightButton">Mouth</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Legs')" class ="rightButton">Legs</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Neck')" class ="rightButton">Neck</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('Accessories')" class ="rightButton">Accessories</button>
        <hr>  
       

        <div id="Backgrounds" ><p class="para">Backgrounds</p>
        <button type="button" class="rightSubButton">Blue50</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Blue60</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Blue70</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Darkblue30</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Darkblue50</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Darkblue70</button>
        <button type="button" class="rightSubButton">Green50</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Green60</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Green70</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Grey40</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Grey70</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Grey80</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Red50</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Red60</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Red70</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Yellow50</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Yellow60</button>
        <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Yellow70</button>
      </div>
        <div id="Ears" ><p class="para">Ears</p>
          <button type="button" class="rightSubButton">Default</button>
          <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Tilt-backward</button>
          <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Tilt-forward</button>
      </div> 



#Backgrounds , #Ears , #Hair , #Eyes , #Legs , #Mouth ,#Neck , #Accessories { 
    display: none; 
  
  }
```

The goal is to get the "rightSubButtons" displayed when ONLY clicking on each of the previous buttons associated with.

Comment: In the interest of content quality, Stack Overflow disallows questions to be asked in duplicate. If you have additional information or need to change something about your original question, please edit it instead of posting a new question altogether. This is a duplicate of [Want buttons be displayed ONLY when clicking on another button with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68553338/want-buttons-be-displayed-only-when-clicking-on-another-button-with-js)

Comment: You could do it this way: assign EVERY button created a class name they have in common. You then hiden those before creating the new buttons and now you show those that are suppose to be shown by picking those with the specific class name and setting them visible using javascript

Comment: I am gong to try that @muzzletov https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983401/muzzletov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the switch statement

visiting https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch for more info.

but if you change the `x` for `id` your code will work
ex:

```js
...
var x = document.getElementById(id);
  console.log(x)//with this console log you will see why you can't use the var x
  switch (id) {
...
```

Comment: there is still a problem. Indeed when clicking on a given button, i get another set of buttons that is nice. but ,when clicking on another button , the group of buttons generated before are still displayed and I want them to be removed and have only the group of buttons of that second button.

Comment: Hi, for that you need to improve your code a lit bit! One way to do that is instead of add the `display:none` in the tag you can use a class show in css. For example: 1 - add a class show in css `show{display:none}` 2- add a `function unShow() {
  var showElements = document.querySelectorAll('.show')
  showElements.forEach(element => {
    element.classList.remove('show')
  })
}`  3- change the myFunction a lit bit too `.... case id="Backgrounds":
        unShow()
        x.classList.add('show'); ....`

Comment: little*** - I made an example: [link](https://codepen.io/cdfortes/pen/VwbMvaq) :)

Comment: Dear @cdfortes https://stackoverflow.com/users/11868835/cdfortes, you made it!! You've fixed the issue. I try to get by in CSS and HTML but JS is still a problem, .. I have studied the theory but I need to practice, practice and practice. Thank you very much!!